# Error: undefined method 'ref' for nil:NilClass on node vagrant-trusty64

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I'm having a problem with my Puppet manifests in my local Vagrant machine. Whenever I try to provision my Vagrant machine, I receive the following output, which I can't seem to find the cause:

```
Error: undefined method `ref' for nil:NilClass on node vagrant-trusty64.lan
Error: undefined method `ref' for nil:NilClass on node vagrant-trusty64.lan
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

puppet apply --modulepath '/tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/modules-0:/etc/puppet/modules' --hiera_config=/tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/hiera.yaml --manifestdir /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests --detailed-exitcodes /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests/vagrant.pp || [ $? -eq 2 ]

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
Error: undefined method `ref' for nil:NilClass on node vagrant-trusty64.lan
Error: undefined method `ref' for nil:NilClass on node vagrant-trusty64.lan
```

Any ideas on where to start debugging?

**Vagrantfile**:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    # Use Phusion's Ubuntu 12.04 box with support for Docker
    config.vm.box = "phusion-open-ubuntu-14.04-amd64"
    config.vm.box_url = "https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/vagrant/boxes/latest/ubuntu-14.04-amd64-vbox.box"
    # Set hostname
    config.vm.hostname = "vagrant-trusty64"

    # Configure the VirtualBox Provider
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        # Give the VM 1GB of RAM
        # vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
    end

    # Provisioning with Puppet Standalone 
    config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
        puppet.hiera_config_path = "conf/puppet/hiera.yaml"
        puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
        puppet.manifest_file  = "vagrant.pp"
        puppet.module_path = "modules"
    end
end
```

Comment: To even get started on this one, you need to pass the `--trace` option to Puppet. I don't know how to do this inside Vagrant.

Comment: Show us the `Vagrantfile`

Comment: @FelixFrank I know how to do it, that'll be my next step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when trying to debug these issues, as [Felix Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3356612/felix-frank) points out in his comment on the question, add Puppet's `--trace` argument to the Puppet arguments that Vagrant uses:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
        # ...
        puppet.options = ["--debug", "--trace"]
    end
end
```

An even better solution:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
        # ...
        if ENV.key?('PUPPET_OPTS')
            puppet.options = ENV['PUPPET_OPTS'].split(' ')
        end
    end
end
```

With the above command, simply define the `PUPPET_OPTS` environment variable when running:

```
PUPPET_OPTS="--trace --debug" vagrant provision
```

This revealed the general point in the Puppet manifests that things were failing. I commented out some stuff and isolated the problem to the following class:

```
class profiles::some::long::path {
    contain a, b, c
}
```

...where `a`, `b`, and `c` were classes inside of `profiles::some::long::path`. The weird thing is that somehow this exact code ran fine last night at some point. [I'm still trying to find out if there's an abridged syntax for including classes in the current class' package.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520179/abbreviated-include-statements-for-modules)